# Where are you headed? VS. Where are you heading?

Tags: sentence-choice

> Where are you headed?

> Where are you heading?

What are the differences between the two sentences, and how should I use them?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. They are two ways of asking people **where/in what direction they are going.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a verb that means **point the front of a moving vessel in a specific direction**, "head" can be used transitively and intransitively. This is a transitive version:

> The pilot headed the ship for home.

I.e., the pilot pointed the ship towards home.

Because **ship** is the direct object of **head**, we can imagine a passive use for the verb:

> The ship has been headed for home by the pilot.

Without the agent of the action:

> The ship has been headed for home.

But no one ever says any of those. Instead, we use the past participle to identify a state rather than an action:

> The ship is headed for home.

Now you can see how we get to this:

> Where are you headed?

It is quite common for English to have both a transitive form of a verb and an intransitive form in which the object of the transitive form becomes the subject of the intransitive form. Thus we can say this:

> The ship is heading home.

By extension, we can also say,

> Where are you heading.

Ultimately, the intended meaning of both versions is the same, and the speaker's choice is largely a matter of habit.